# Differential equations - Initial value problem - Uniqueness of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking to show that $x' =3t^2 - te^{-x^2}$ with $x(0) = 0$ has a unique solution. Using a theorem, if I can show that $|f(x,t) - f(y,t)| < L|x-y|$ for all $t>0$, then there exists a unique solution.

I'm having trouble showing that the $L$ does not depend on $t$. From the above, I get to $|t| |e^{-y^2}-e^{-x^2}| <|t| |x-y|$ from an earlier exercise showing that $|e^{-y^2}-e^{-x^2}|<1 |x-y|$.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In the inequality $|f(x,t) - f(y,t)| < L|x-y|$ you quantify over $t$, but not over $x$ and $y$. Please do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you please clarify?

Comment: I'm trying to use this theorem to prove. 

If there exists an r > 0 and a constant L such that the function f satisfies
|f(x, t) − f(y, t)| ≤ L|x − y| for all x, y ∈ B(0, r) and all t ≥ t0, 
then there exists a t1 > t0 such that the differential equation
x′(t) = f(x(t), t), x(t0) = x0 ∈ B(0, r),
has a unique solution for all t ∈ [t0, t1].

Answer (score 2):

Existence and uniqueness over small intervals is guaranteed by what you have. Assume you have two solutions $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ with $x_{1}(0)=x_{2}(0)$. Let $T$ be the set of $t > 0$ such that $x_{1}=x_{2}$ on $[0,t]$. Show that $T$ is an open subset of $(0,\infty)$ and that $T$ is a closed subset of $(0,\infty)$. By connectedness, you'll know that $T=(0,\infty)$, which is what you want. I don't see any obstacles to the argument in your particular case.